# Ruby On Rails ActiveRecord is looking for singular table name, not plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

By default ActiveRecord looks for plural table names. So in my application I can reference the `armours` table by using the `Armour` class which looks like this.

```rb
class Armour < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I can call it in the console by running this which correctly calls the plural table name `armours`.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Armour.all
  Armour Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "armours".* FROM "armours"
  <output omittid>
```

However, I have another model named Equipment which does not reference the correct plural table name `equipments` but instead tries to look for the singular table name `equipment`. This is the only class that does this and I can't figure out why.

```rb
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :soldier_equipment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :soldier, through: :soldier_equipment
end
```

```rb
irb(main):002:0> Equipment.all
  Equipment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "equipment".* FROM "equipment"
An error occurred when inspecting the object: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:"PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation \"equipment\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT \"equipment\".* FROM \"equipment\"\n
```

This is the only model that does this and I can't figure out why. The schema.rb file looks fine and all the migrations succeed. If I add the following line to my `Equipment` model everything works fine, but I can't tell where it's getting the non-standard table name from.

```rb
self.table_name = "equipments"
```

Where does ActiveRecord define the table names?

ruby version: 3.2.2
rails version: 7.0.4.3
activerecord version: 7.0.4.3
PostgreSQL 15.2 (Homebrew)
Macbook air with M1 CPU

Comment: Equipment is part of the `uncountable` default inflections in rails ([full list](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb)), so by default rails will not pluralize it

Comment: Well gosh dang it. Thank you kind person!

Comment: @AbM wow, it's crazy how random and semi-useless that list is. But I'm sure i'll appreachiate it next time I make an Octopus model.

Comment: @max  You'll also need a validation in the `Tickle` model to have ten `tickles` per octopus 

Comment: @StaticMethod was the `Equipment` generated using `rails g model`?  If so, it is weird that it generated an `equipments` table instead of `equipment`. I tried it on my end, and it created an `equipment` (singular) table.

Comment: Now that I think about it the table was initially named something else and I changed the name to equipments because that’s what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

rails use inflections by default and some names after plural still in singular
so if you want to change that just follow these steps.

Find the `inflections.rb` file in the `/config/initializers` folder, or simply create this file if it doesn't exist. Then write this code

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular "equipment", "equipments"
end
```

inflections always run the `irregular` method first, so your "equipments" will always be plural